# Is it possible to do something akin to a 'traceroute' on an Elasticsearch search request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm confronted with a problem here at my place of employment.   We are A/B'ing a couple of routing strategies in our Elasticsearch installation.  I'm responsible for testing it using JMeter tests so my only feedback on the difference of routing strategies is basically just plain ol' response times from certain API requests.

I would like more in-depth analysis.

Is it possible to execute some sort of traceroute-ish request (via the ES API) that could provide me with some more information about the nature of how the search requests are sent, what shards were involved and how the search was merged?   I'm still on the on-ramp to learning this ES stuff but I'm beginning to pick up a little speed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure and enable the Slow Log, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html

You can define the thresholds for the query and fetch phase. These logs also show the node and shard where the query was executed.

Example from the Elasticsearch documentation page:

`[2030-08-30T11:59:37,786][WARN ][i.s.s.query] [node-0] [index6][0] took[78.4micros], took_millis[0], total_hits[0 hits], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[1], source[{"query":{"match_all":{"boost":1.0}}}], id[MY_USER_ID],`

Any tracing done by a service that uses ES needs to be done there. Here, you could use Zipkin for example.